# How to restrict duplication of values in dynamically created select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a table whose rows can  be created dynamically. Each dynamically created rows will have two text boxes and one select box.

I use the select box to let the user to select a product of their choice.

The thing is that, I want to restrict the user from select the same product more than one.

For example, If a user selects Balloon in the first row and clicks add to add new row, the option for choosing balloon should not be there in the select box.

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/14/)

It would be great if there is any jquery approach for this, or even raw javasript would be fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code looks a little like its obfuscated my friend :)

Comment: Hmm, why is tagged with jQuery? It seems like you're not using it in your demo. When clicking "Add" you should go through all available select fields (or store that info in object/array), find what options already selected and remove them from newly created select.

Comment: I think nobody is touching this because: 1. Your code is obfuscated; 2. You are creating elements using huge strings; 3. The question is not well-thought-out. What if a user changes a previous select after adding a row? If you want to exclude options, just iterate $("#insSpec select option:selected") and exclude the text of each option from your new select.

Answer (score 1):

It's not cool, but looks good enough for a mockup. Please have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td><td>Mfd_date</td><td>RRX(Qty)</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="selector">
        </select>
      </td> 
    </tr> 
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var products = ['Baloon', 'Nachos', 'Cola'];  

    $('#selector').change(function() {
    var product = $('#selector').val();
        products.splice(products.indexOf(product), 1);
        addRow(product);
        updateSelector();
    });

    var addRow = function(product) {
        var row = $('<tr><td>' + product + '</td><td><input></td><td><input></td><td><button>Delete</button></td></tr>');
        $('table tr:last').before(row);
        $('button', row).click(function() {
          products.push($('td:first', row).text());  
          row.remove();
          updateSelector();
        });
    }

    var updateSelector = function() {
      $('#selector').toggle(products.length > 0);
      $('#selector').empty();
      $('#selector').append('<option></option>');
      for(var i=0; i<products.length; i++)
        $('#selector').append('<option>' + products[i] + '</option>');
    }

    updateSelector();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you wanted to use your initial approach and just make it work instead of a complete rewrite. So you could change your **insSpec** function to something like this

```
function insSpec()
    {
    rl=document.getElementById("insSpecc").rows.length;
    var a=document.getElementById("insSpecc").insertRow(rl);
    var h=a.insertCell(0);
    var f=a.insertCell(1);
    var m=a.insertCell(2);
    var n=a.insertCell(3);
    var select ='<div class="separator"><select id="prod_name'+rl+'" name="prod_name">';

    var prevSelectedProducts = new Array();

    $("select option:selected").each(function()
    {
        prevSelectedProducts.push($(this).text());
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < availableProducts.length; ++i) {
        if($.inArray(availableProducts[i], prevSelectedProducts) == -1) {
            select += '<option value="'+availableProducts[i].toLowerCase()+'">'+availableProducts[i]+'</option>';
        }
    } 

    delete prevSelectedProducts;

    h.innerHTML=select+'</select>';
    f.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="mfd_date[]" id="mfd_date'+rl+'" size="5"  />';
    m.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="client_rrx[]"  id="client_rrx'+rl+'" size="5"  />';
    n.innerHTML='<button   class="del_img" onClick="delSpec(this)"/>Delete</button></div>';

    }
```

I would probably dynamically build the select options the first time to though and this implementation doesn't hinder you from changing already entered selections. That should probably be hindered by turning the select box into plain text or something when a selection has been done.